# Converting a hex to integer in Python - equivalent for ToInt64 in C#

Tags: c#, python, sha256

I am trying to convert a sha256 hash to an integer.This works in C# but I cannot get it work in Python.

```
C# Version :
string inputString = "TestString";
            SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create();
            byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
            //Read the Bytes and print
            var sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
            sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes: " + sb);            
            Console.WriteLine("ConvertedInt: " + BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes));
Output :
Bytes: 6dd79f2770a0bb38073b814a5ff000647b37be5abbde71ec9176c6ce0cb32a27
ConvertedInt: 4088037490330425197
```

The above prints the bytes and Integer value as expected. Trying to do the same in Python but couldnt convert to the same integer number.

```
import hashlib
hashobj = hashlib.sha256("TestString".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(hashobj)

#Tried Option 1:
print(f"Option 1 prints:\r")
print(int(hashobj,32))

#Tried Option 2:
print(f"Option 1 prints:\r")
print(int(hashobj,16))

Output:
6dd79f2770a0bb38073b814a5ff000647b37be5abbde71ec9176c6ce0cb32a27
Option 1 prints:
428476861264242379186014021585258195649378281633207959348811042267114033125399631735390859241543
Option 1 prints:
49683071055471546380350462257487304408748464885741562355821390565893091830311
```

How can I convert the hashobj to a 64 bit int in python? Just trying to get the same integer value in python, Thanks for any help.

#### Edit 1 :

Following the answer from @Sweeper and @Recursing, was able to proceed further but have an issue when the resulting integer is signed.
Case 1: Hex to Integer is +ve, when I try a modulo the int(8bytes) with a number, say 300, gives the expected result 108.
Case 2 & Case 3: Hex to Integer is -ve, then I have to read variable mumber of bytes, 7 bytes for Case 2 and 9 bytes for Case 3, then modulo by 300 gives the expected result 108.

***Question:*** How to determine the number of bytes to read when the integer is -ve, to get the same result? Thank you.

```
#Case 1
hash_bytes = hashlib.sha256("098C10227K3R".encode('utf-8')).digest()
print("Case 1 : Is Positive : {}".format(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True) > 0))
print("Case 1 : IntegerValue : {}".format(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True)))
print("Case 1 : 8 Bytes:")
print(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True) % 300)

#Case 2
hash_bytes = hashlib.sha256("159YK282MS3T".encode('utf-8')).digest()
print("Case 2 : Is Positive : {}".format(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True) > 0))
print("Case 2 : IntegerValue : {}".format(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True)))
print("Case 2 : 8 Bytes:")
print(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True) % 300)
print("Case 2 : 7 Bytes:")
print(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:7], byteorder="little", signed=True) % 300)

#Case 3
print("Case 3:")
hash_bytes = hashlib.sha256("17FK427W501L".encode('utf-8')).digest()
print("Case 3 : Is Positive : {}".format(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True) > 0))
print("Case 3 : IntegerValue : {}".format(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True)))
print("Case 3 - 8 Bytes:")
print(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True) % 300)
print("Case 3 - 9 Bytes:")
print(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:9], byteorder="little", signed=True) % 300)

Output:
Case 1 : Is Positive : True
Case 1 : IntegerValue : 9212408962392255108
Case 1 : 8 Bytes:
108
Case 2 : Is Positive : False
Case 2 : IntegerValue : -5822649536180381508
Case 2 : 8 Bytes:
192
Case 2 : 7 Bytes:
Case 3 : IntegerValue 7 bytes: 14015580891781308
108
Case 3:
Case 3 : Is Positive : False
Case 3 : IntegerValue : -2669588811718081008
Case 3 - 8 Bytes:
192
Case 3 - 9 Bytes:
Case 3 : IntegerValue 9 bytes: -445391446580747319792
108
```

Comment: You only need the first 8 bytes (that's what the C# code does).

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, it works!

Comment: I feel like this doesn't have much to do with reading the bytes. Rather it's because python's `%` operator computes the modulo, whereas C#'s `%` operator computes the remainder. In the case of a negative number, just make it positive, `% 300`, then make it negative again.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, thats exactly the issue. Some read here helped : [link]https://rob.conery.io/2018/08/21/mod-and-remainder-are-not-the-same/ `absVal = abs(int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[:8], byteorder="little", signed=True))
print("Case 3: Absolute : {}".format(absVal % 300))` gives the correct result for case 2 & 3. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sweeper said, the C# code keeps only the first 8 bytes of the hash, and converts it to integer

In python you could do:

```py
import hashlib
hash_bytes = hashlib.sha256("TestString".encode('utf-8')).digest()
first_bytes = hash_bytes[:8]
print(int.from_bytes(first_bytes, byteorder="little", signed=True))
```

An alternative would be using the `struct` module in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

```py
print(struct.unpack("q", first_bytes))
```

Comment: @Sweeper, have an issue while reading the first 8 bytes incase of a negative  integer. Kindly check Edit 1. Thanks.